# Why is this code not drawing the start button I want?

Tags: python, image, pygame

I have tried a lot and still don't understand why it doesn't load the button.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((3840,2160))
running = True
mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

pygame.display.set_caption("GermanBall")
bg = pygame.image.load("Tan.jpg")
icon = pygame.image.load("box.png")
button1 = pygame.image.load("shirt.png").convert_alpha()
class Button():
    def __init__(self,x,y,image):
        self.image = image 
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = (x,y)

    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.image,(self.rect.x,self.rect.y)) 
start = Button(0,0,button1)


pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
while running == True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    start.draw()
    screen.blit(bg,(0,0))
    pygame.display.update()
```

I want the button to load. It doesn't give me an error and just doesn't load.

Comment: `screen.blit(bg,(0,0))` immediately erases everything you've drawn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call `start.draw()` after `screen.blit(bg,(0,0))`, but before `pygame.display.update()`. Note: `screen.blit(bg, (0,0)` draws the background image over the entire screen, so that everything that was previously drawn is overdrawn. `pygame.display.update()` updates the display and makes all changes to the display *Surface* visible at once:

```py
while running == True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    # draw background
    screen.blit(bg,(0,0))

    # draw button
    start.draw()

    # update display
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: i had also thought of this as a solution but unfortunately it still doesnt work no matter when i draw my button but thank you for answering

Comment: @vivaantomar Your problem is not reproducible. It works fine for me.

Comment: Maybe something is wrong with my image i'm using then..... thanks for the answer